# can we have multiple azure active directory tenant mapped to a single subscription?

Tags: azure, active-directory

can we have multiple azure active directory tenant mapped to a single subscription? This is because we want to avoid creating multiple subscriptions for each test environment

Answer (score 0):

As discussed earlier today, it is only possible to do this on the Classic Portal, which is coming to End of Life as of November 30th. Microsoft doesn't have any plans to introduce this into the new portal anytime soon it seems, and may even plan to keep the relationship 1:1 for Azure going forward.